# Manipulating response from the Server ,before passing to Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `jquery Datatable` plugin to display a table.The problem I am facing is that I want to manipulate the server response each time before passing to the `datatable`.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out the answer to this.
We can use fnServerData for this.

Here is a sample

```
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {                                         $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                                                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                                                fnCallback(json.Output);
                                            } );


                                    },
```